# For piecewise $\mathcal C^1$ path there exists a $\mathcal C^1$ reparametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I want to show the following.

> Let $\gamma :[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a piecewise continuously differentiable path. Then there exists a reparametrization of $\gamma$ which is continuously differentiable.

There was a hint provided which says that you need to "slow down" at the corners to make the path differentiable at the corner. This makes sense but I don't know how I can use this. I only have the beginning like so:

" Let $\xi = \{t_{0} = a < t_{1} < \ldots < t_{K} = b\}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ such that $\gamma _{\mid [t_{k-1},t_{k}]}$ is continuously differentiable for all $k = 1,\ldots,K$. I need to find $\psi:[\tilde a,\tilde b] \to [a,b]$ such that the reparametrization $\tilde \gamma: [\tilde a,\tilde b] \to \Bbb R^n$ with $\tilde \gamma(t)=(\gamma \circ \psi)(t)$ is continuously differentiable. "

Can somebody give me a hint how to prove this? Thanks.

Comment: Take a $\psi$ with $\psi'(s)=0$ whenever $\psi(s)\in\xi$.

Comment: @JanBohr Thanks. Also I need to guarantee that $\psi$ is continuously differentiable, monotonically increasing and bijective. So $\psi'(s)$ needs to be close to zero around the partition points too. How do I contstruct such a $\psi$?

Comment: If $\psi$ is continuously differentiable, then $\psi'(s)$ will automatically be close to $0$ around partition points. Concerning the other points, you're right - that's exactly what you need. For a single partition point $t_0$ you can use something like $\psi(t)=(t-t_0)^3$. For several partition points you can paste such functions together.